# Grant Read access to Azure Active Directory Group in SQL DW (Synapse)

Tags: azure-active-directory, ssms, active-directory-group, azure-synapse

Can anybody help me with this, I'm stuck and reading didn't get me anywhere :(

My question is related to Azure Active Directory Group and SQL DW. I want to give database read access to an Azure Active Directory Group (ADD group). I took these steps for that:

- I made two groups in ADD as **Azure AnalytcisDW Admin Users** and **Azure AnalytcisDW Database Users**, each with a bunch of users.
- Then, I went to Azure Portal, selected my SQL DW and added **Azure AnalytcisDW Admin Users** group as *Active Directory Admin* (image below).
- Then, I checked in SSMS and saw **Azure AnalytcisDW Admin Users** group is under mater=>Security=>Users (see image below)

Now I want to give **Azure AnalytcisDW Database Users** group the (database) read permission (using SSMS or anything). I couldn't figure out how. I read a bunch of stuff for it and couldn't find my way through, such as:

[Grant Access to SQL Server Table to AD user](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ef6b02ea-f24f-4b85-9347-fe7f02cbf84a/grant-access-to-sql-server-table-to-ad-user?forum=sqldataaccess)

[Adding Users to Azure SQL Databases](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5242/adding-users-to-azure-sql-databases/)

[image: Active Directory Admin in SQL DW (Portal)]

[image: SSMS]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to do the same by using the below commands where db_users(same as your Azure AnalytcisDW Database Users) is the active directory group and I have used an id from db_admin (same as your Azure AnalytcisDW Admin Users) to connect to Synapse.

[image]

Ref doc : [RoleAssign](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addrolemember-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), [AADGroupUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-user-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Thanks @HarithaMaddi-MSFT for it. unfortunately, I tried it and got this error:
"Cannot alter the role 'db_datareader', because it does not exist or you do not have permission."
Should I make this under `master` or a `database`?
Btw, how this makes a connection to my `user` AD group? I can't see it anywhere in ssms

Comment: also in the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addrolemember-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) you shared it says "This syntax is not supported by serverless SQL pool in Azure Synapse Analytics."

Comment: Hey @mas,
You need to execute the above queries in the database itself.
To see the role which you created , execute the below query in the database:

`SELECT DP1.name AS DatabaseRoleName,   
   isnull (DP2.name, 'No members') AS DatabaseUserName   
 FROM sys.database_role_members AS DRM  
 RIGHT OUTER JOIN sys.database_principals AS DP1  
   ON DRM.role_principal_id = DP1.principal_id  
 LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.database_principals AS DP2  
   ON DRM.member_principal_id = DP2.principal_id  
WHERE DP1.type IN ( 'R')
ORDER BY DP1.name;`

Comment: Also, you need to login via an AD account only to execute this query of creation of new AD user

Comment: seems that you have to make users under `master` as well as any database you want to assign a role.

Comment: To run any active directory role grant commands, please use active directory admin account to login into Synapse